# Tailwind CSS too large

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

I got a problem using tailwind css with Vue3. Looking at the network tab it's size is 4.4 MB.

The postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    cssnano: {}
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./frontend/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}",
    "./app/views/**/*.html.erb"
  ],
  prefix: 'tw-',
  ...
```

cssnano is added using yarn.
yarn.lock

```
cssnano-preset-default@^5.2.12:
cssnano@5.1.13

tailwindcss@^2.1.4:
```

Importing tailwind in main.css which itself is imported in the vue entrypoints.

```
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
```

Whether in development nor in production the size of main.css changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, I solved it. The version of tailwind I'm using ain't compatible with the "content" setting in the current documentation. I still have to use this syntax:

```
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: [
      "./frontend/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}",
      "./app/views/**/*.html.erb"
    ],
  },
```

Also needed to do a re-build of the prod environment.

Comment: You should use the v3 of Tailwind if possible, then `content` will be the one to use: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Comment: @kissu Already upgraded, thanks. :)

Comment: There is no purge in v3: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources

Answer (score 0):

You have also the mode JIT it will generates your styles on-demande  https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode